# I have an result JSON, then i see the output with var_demp, but it not show full result

Tags: xampp, xdebug, var-dump, php

Here is my output. See end of line. **The output just gives me '...'.**

```
      public 'results' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(..)[18]
              ...
```

And this is my code to debug the result.

```
var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using xdebug in background, add following code :

```
ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_children", -1);
ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_data", -1);
ini_set("xdebug.var_display_max_depth", -1);
```

check if your problem is solved or not